# Hazelcast log pattern interpretation

Tags: log4j, hazelcast, vert.x

in my app the Hazelcast is logging the events like:

> 08:41:52.797 [hz._hzInstance_1_docker.generic-operation.thread-0] INFO c.h.internal.cluster.ClusterService - [1.2.3.4]:5701 [docker] [3.9.2]

My question is what the **[docker]** here stands for? Is it some env var?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the group name of your cluster

From `hazelcast.xml` if you have it

```
    <group>
            <name>something</name>
            <password/>
    </group>
```

Or

```
config.getGroupConfig().getName()
```

if you set your config from Java.